# What does "lower flatness" mean in airfoil terminology?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, terminology, airfoil

What does lower flatness mean in these parameters of a Glenn Martin airfoil?
[image]

Comment: Just a guess - something to do with the amount of deviation from a planar bottom of the airfoil.